# How to tell if the user is scrolling down or up

Tags: javascript

I did basic animation of when the user is going down the page, the content will appear. I also did that when he is going up it reappears. Explaining in a clearer way. When it goes down, the content appears and as it goes down, the content that had already appeared, disappears again and will reappear if it goes up the page, making the effect again.
The problem is that the animation when it is going up, it occurs very high, it is not the same way when you are going down the page.
Is there a simple way to know if it is scrolling down or up? So I could change this value.